# distinguish hotlinking and direct links of images

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any way to distinguish direct image hits from hotlinked images?

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

If user directly goes to "page.com/image17.gif" he should be redirected to "page.com/page17.html"

If someone embeds an image on another page, he should see "notHotlink.jpg"

My website and search engines should be unaffected so their indexing still works for image searches

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.mydomain.com/angryman.gif [R,L]
```

Comment: That only solves the hotlink problem, right?  What about whiteflagging search engines and the direct link redirect?